# Does placing an object in a list move its location in memory?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory

For example,

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct* myStruct;
};

MyStruct a;
MyStruct b;

a.myStruct = &b;
b.myStruct = &a;

std::list<MyStruct> myList;

myList.push_back(a);
MyStruct* listA = &myList.back();

myList.push_back(b);
MyStruct* listB = &myList.back();
```

Are `&a` and `listA` the same? Will `a.myStruct` still work as a pointer to `b`? Will `a.myStruct` work as a pointer to the `b` inside the list?

Does adding an object to a list create a copy of the object or keep the original object in memory and just use a reference to it?

My understanding is that the list is implemented as a doubly-linked list so it shouldn't need to copy or move the original object but I'm unsure if that actually holds true.

Comment: pretty sure that this code doesn't compile, however storing a pointer to a object in a list does not "move" the object, it just copies the pointer in the list

Comment: @Berto99 We have an answer section!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does placing an object in a list move its location in memory?

No, it creates a new object (a copy) at another location in memory.

All standard containers "own" their elements, and they do that by copying the things you give them (or moving them, where applicable).

> Are `a` and `listA` the same?

No.

> Will `a->myStruct` still work as a pointer to `b`?

Yes. This has not changed.

Comment: he is copying the pointer to the object, not the object itself, so it won't compile

Comment: @Berto99 I'm treating the first half of the snippet as being the broken half.

Comment: That is not at all obvious from your answer.

Comment: @cigien It doesn't matter; the key point is that a standard container owns what you put into it, which means copies of a pre-existing object (unless you specifically move it). That's it.

Comment: That much is true. But your answer responds to specific pieces of OP's code, and as it stands, there's no real way to tell what that code means.

Comment: @cigien Regardless, everything in it is factually accurate. But I guess we don't want to help the OP today. That's okay. We can try again tomorrow. :) Good night.

Comment: I'd love to help the OP, but IMO it's considerably more helpful for them to learn how to ask a question properly, rather than helping them this one time, with one explanation.

Comment: Fortunately, we've achieved both.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was exactly what I was wondering.